# LTSpice showing negative transistor power

Tags: power, transistors, ltspice

I'm using LTSpice to model a LC oscillator, driven by a NPN transistor. When I used the power calculating function on the transistor, LTSpice indicated that during part of the cycle the power dissipated in the transistor is negative. I was under the impression that transistors always dissipate power resistively since they don't store energy in E or B fields.

So my question is, what am I to make of this? Should I take the absolute value or something?

EDIT: As requested, here's the asc file: http://pastebin.com/F1wBPXVy

[image: Pic showing the transistor power in LTSpice.]

Comment: Since you have it available, it would be most convenient for people trying to see for themselves to provide the .asc file. Anyways have a look at the transistor connectors in which direction current is flowing tehre.

Comment: Not that the asc format is just text, so http://pastebin.com and similar work well enough for uploading that.

Comment: Also as a general comment, some (MPZ) opamp macromodels contain inductors, but I don't yet know what LTspice has for that 2N???? (hard to read the number in your pic).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: right click, open in new tab. its a 2n5550. Btw. I am pretty sure he exceeds the emitter base voltage.

Comment: Yeah, this is a 2n5550. And yes, in real life the transistor would be burning. But it doesn't matter, I found the same behavior with a variety of transistors.

Comment: Added the asc file to the OP.

Comment: Vbe is swinging both ways, so surely above the reverse breakdown voltage. http://imgur.com/lUGHYN1 Probably because of the inductors somehow.

Comment: From http://www.edaboard.co.uk/behavior-transistor-models-t537679.html "As for the BVbe, so far, at least in Ltspice, that value isn't set in the stock parts".

Comment: So, yeah, LTspice thinks you can have hundreds of milliamps flowing both in and out of that transistor's base... http://imgur.com/RxiK8jU

Comment: Woah, I hadn't noticed that before. What the heck is it doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under static conditions, and in the long run, you're perfectly right: transistors will always dissipate power.

However, for short durations transistors can both absorb and deliver energy. This is because of the intrinsic *capacitance* between their terminals. This capacitance appears both in the depletion regions of reverse-biased (and forward-biased) PN junctions, as well as base charge storage required for minority carrier diffusion.

In your case, the inductor stores kinetic energy (as current), and pumps this current toward the transistor's collector. The transistor is off, so its collector voltage flies up to \$100\rm{V}\$ -- in other words, the inductor's kinetic energy is transferred to potential energy (as voltage) in whatever capacitance hangs on that node from C3 and Q1. Once the inductor runs out of steam, the capacitors deliver their energy back to it. It works exactly like a child on a swingset. Q1's model shows a base-collector capacitance \$C_{BC}\$ of about \$1.6\rm{pF}\$, which puts it in the same ballpark as C3's \$3\rm{pF}\$. Nothing to scoff at.

Comment: As an addendum here, there quite a few cases when that base capacitance needs to be considered. Switching power supplies for example: https://books.google.com/books?id=zWcpOJNz7n8C&pg=PA64